# fetching externally hosted db's table from within the local mysql server

Tags: mysql, mysqld-multi

Let's say we have a mysql database on localhost with table A and table B.

Is it possible to fetch details from a 3rd party mysql server to which we have login info and which allows external access?

Let's say there are 3 tables in the database we can connect to - table A2, B2 and C2.

How do you fetch the rows from table C2 and make it VIRTUALY accessible (as table C) from within the original mysql server (just like A and B), just like if it was hosted on it?

Answer (score 3):

I normally would not recommend this but here it goes...

**If the tables on the remote DB Server are MyISAM**, try using the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html">FEDERATED Stroage Engine. First starters, find out if the FEDERATED Storage Engine is Enabled. This what I get running `SHOW ENGINES;` in MySQL 5.5.12 for Windows:

```
mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In MySQL 5.5.12 for Windows it is not enabled

So, I added this to my.ini

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

I then restarted MySQL on my machine

```
mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| FEDERATED          | YES     | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Now, it is running !!!

On your remote server perform this query:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE C2\G
```

This will show you the create table statement for C2.

Now just append the URL of the remote table usign the CONNECTION clause.

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-create-connection.html)

For that link

> The format of the connection string is as follows: 
>   scheme://user_name[:password]@host_name[:port_num]/db_name/tbl_name
>   Where:
>
> • scheme: A recognized connection protocol. Only mysql is supported as
>   the scheme value at this point.
>
> • user_name: The user name for the connection. This user must have
>   been created on the remote server, and must have suitable privileges
>   to perform the required actions (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and so forth)
>   on the remote table.
>
> • password: (Optional) The corresponding password for user_name.
>
> • host_name: The host name or IP address of the remote server.
>
> • port_num: (Optional) The port number for the remote server. The
>   default is 3306.
>
> • db_name: The name of the database holding the
>   remote table.
>
> • tbl_name: The name of the remote table. The name of the local and
>   the remote table do not have to match.

Sample connection strings:

```
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database/tablename'
CONNECTION='mysql://username@hostname/database/tablename'
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname/database/tablename'
```

Suppose that table `C2` in the mydb database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE C2
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Just append the `CONNECTION` clause and run it on the Local Server:

```
use mydb
CREATE TABLE C
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname/mydb/C2';
```

Finally, in MySQL on your local machine, you should be able to access the C2 table like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mydb.C;
```

Comment: Rolando's answer works great with one small change - the ENGINE specification when you create it on your local server must be FEDERATED rather than MyISAM.