# Mysql federated engine table creation error

Tags: mysql, storage-engine

I am trying to create a federated table on my local machine which suppose to connect to my another machine which also in my local network. I have enabled federated engine on both machines and is shown when I run this command show engines.

Below is my syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE fedTransfer( `fedID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `transferID` INT, `outletFromID` INT, `employeeToID` INT, `transferStatus` ENUM('y'), `transferToDate` DATE, `transferToTime` TIME, PRIMARY KEY (`fedID`) ) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED;
COMMENT='mysql://root:passw1@192.168.2.103/mptest/fedTransfer';
```

Below is the error I get when I run this on sqlyog.

```
Error Code: 1
Can't create/write to file 'server name: '' doesn't exist!' (Errcode: 1408685900)

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.047 sec
---------------------------------------------------

Query: COMMENT='mysql://root:passw1@192.168.2.103/mptest/fedTransfer'

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT='mysql://root:passw1@192.168.2.103/mptest/fedTransfer'' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of MySQL is this ???

Comment: The version is mysql 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## OBSERVATION #1

According to [the Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image: MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide]

Page 434 shows an example using `COMMENT` to establish a federated connection. Unfortunately, the book was written when MySQL 5.0.13 was released. Now, you use `CONNECTION` instead of `COMMENT`,

Here are my past answers (over a year ago) where I use `CONNECTION` instead of `COMMENT`:

- `Jun 28, 2012` : [Connecting remote MySQL database to local MySQL database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20095/connecting-remote-mysql-database-to-local-mysql-database/20097#20097)
- `Jan 04, 2012` : [fetching externally hosted db's table from within the local mysql server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10164/fetching-externally-hosted-dbs-table-from-within-the-local-mysql-server/10165#10165)

## OBSERVATION #2

You have this:

```
CREATE TABLE fedTransfer( `fedID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `transferID` INT, `outletFromID` INT, `employeeToID` INT, `transferStatus` ENUM('y'), `transferToDate` DATE, `transferToTime` TIME, PRIMARY KEY (`fedID`) ) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED;
COMMENT='mysql://root:passw1@192.168.2.103/mptest/fedTransfer';
```

Remove the semicolon from the back of the word FEDERATED

## EPILOGUE

Your code should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fedTransfer( `fedID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `transferID` INT, `outletFromID` INT, `employeeToID` INT, `transferStatus` ENUM('y'), `transferToDate` DATE, `transferToTime` TIME, PRIMARY KEY (`fedID`) ) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://root:passw1@192.168.2.103/mptest/fedTransfer';
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I just replace the word comment to connection and it created it without any error. But the remote machine must be power up rite? Another thing if remote machine I put the table engine as innodb is it fine or should I change to myisam?

Comment: My next step is that once the data is insert on my local machine and on the remote machine I want to trigger on insert to update some other table is that possible?

Comment: Federated tables only work with MyISAM. No other storage engines. Before Sun bought MySQL and Oracle bought Sun, MySQL AB was planning to have the federate storage engine talk to different types of databases, including Oracle. Now than Oracle is the grandfather of MySQL, I don't believe the federated storage engine will be worked on to connect outside of MyISAM tables.

Comment: You cannot define a trigger on a federated table, but you can make a trigger on a real table insert to or update a federated table.

Comment: Since myisam so kind of dangerous for me. The reason I am moving to federated is because I am having an application which need to do distributed transaction. So at times it fails when I do individual commit. So I was thinking to put everything under one commit and do away with distributed transaction. So if my transaction fail then the federated insert will still go through rite?

Comment: @Yes I only plan to run the trigger on the real table on the remote machine not where the federated table it. So that will work right/

Comment: Since MyISAM is not transactional, there are no rollback mechanisms to protect data from trickling over to the federated table. If you must have distributional transactional behavior, think about using Percona XtraDB Cluster.

Comment: Will the percona xtradb work on windows platform? The issue is that my setup is every local server will have one copy of the db. The central server will have one additional db known as hq db. So when transaction happen there are some table need to be inserted for hq db and some need to be for the copy of local server db found in the central server.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA btw the federated engine works with any MySQL storage engine on the far end -- InnoDB, MEMORY, ARCHIVE, etc., because it uses a normal MySQL *client* connection against the far end, nothing proprietary.  However, a remote InnoDB table behaves like you would expect a MyISAM table to act if involved in a transaction.